# Best practice for monitoring and killing an activity from a background service?

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way of using `ActivityManager` to programmatically monitor when a package is running/executed, and then to programmatically kill it. I can do it on demand using `manager.killBackgroundProcesses(processName)` with 2.2, and my code works fine for that, but i'd like to register a background service monitor if possible.. Or some sort of an intent launching monitor for the specific package name?

What would be the most efficient and dependable way to do this?

Note: This isn't for any sort of a behind-the-scenes, malicious kill... I am calling `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />` in my manifest, so users will know exactly what the app does.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best practice would be using the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule your polling. The downside is that the AlarmManager only polls on a preset number of intervals.  The smallest interval is 15 minutes.  For majority of circumstances, I think this is enough.

Comment: I need it to be relatively instant.. or within seconds or so. I don't think constantly polling would be very efficient.

Comment: Well, it's either going to be polling, or find some way of getting notified of package launch.

Why do you need to poll that fast? If you're building an app to prevent unwanted bloatwares from starting, this is counter-intuitive. Because as soon as you kill it, the Android system will restart it again.  If that's the case then you need to look into preventing the program from starting instead of trying to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

> i'd like to register a background service monitor if possible

There is no such concept in Android.

> Or some sort of an intent launching monitor for the specific package name?

There is no such concept in Android.

> I need it to be relatively instant.. or within seconds or so. I don't think constantly polling would be very efficient.

Then you will simply have to live with inefficiency, or don't write the app. Android is not set up to support apps like the one you are trying to write.